# Can I share a web application's consumer key and secret using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine?

Tags: iphone, twitter, oauth, mgtwitterengine

I'd like to enable users of my app to associate their twitter accounts so that some application interaction is automatically tweeted.

Users can already associate their twitter accounts via the web interface, and I'd like them to be able to do the same from the mobile (iOS) app.

The problem is, when the application is registered as a web app, a callback URL is specified. So when users log into twitter using SA_OAuthTwitterEngine, the response is redirected to that URL, and the callback events on the client never fire.

Can I use SA_OAuthTwitterEngine, and override the callback parameter (nullify it) so that I get the same interaction (PIN) as a desktop client?

Comment: I'm not familiar with SA_OauthTwitterEngine but if it is compliant with the OAuth protocol you should be able to send a callback URL to Twitter with your custom scheme and automatically launch back the application from inside Safari to continue the authentication process inside your app. Tell me if you need details on this. Btw, PIN sucks and a browser inside the app is security theater.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, were you able to override the callback param in SA_OAuthTwitterEngine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a mobile client, best to use [xAuth](https://dev.twitter.com/pages/xauth). Using the pin method is suboptimal for mobile. After all your application isn't a web app.

The new [MGTwitterEngine](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGTwitterEngine) has xAuth support, so switching should be painless :)